# HTML show and hide not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have an HTML document with headings, when you click on the heading it expands and when you click on it again it collapses.
This works perfectly with most browsers except Firefox Mozilla. When I open it with Firefox Mozilla the headings do not want to expand at all.

Code below:

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

i {
  border: solid #ffb200;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.down {
  color: #ffb200;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.right {
  color: #ffb200;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.mainnav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = event.target.nextElementSibling,
      y = event.target.firstChild;
    if (x.style.display === 'none' || x.style.display === '') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
      y.classList.add("down");
      y.classList.remove("right");
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
      y.classList.remove("down");
      y.classList.add("right");
    }
  }
</script>

<h3 class="sidebar-heading">
  <a class="sidebar-heading" href="#logins"> <u>SYSTEM LOGINS</u></a>
</h3>
<h4 onclick="myFunction(event);" class="sidebar-heading2"><i class="right" style="top:-50px"></i> Login types</h4>
<div class="mainnav">
  <nav id="mainnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Admin">login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Student">Student login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Guest">Guest login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry I only noticed it now when you mentioned it. The error appears under Console in Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you're trying to reference the global `event` parameter you passed to your inline `onclick` handler but you haven't referenced it as a parameter in your function.

Change `myFunction()` to `myFunction( e )` as you should be referencing anything you pass into a function as an argument. You can use any argument name you'd like, but keep it descriptive so you know what you're working with when you reference it in your function body. `e` is a common name used for an event object.

Some browsers give you access to the global `event` object and others don't. That's why it worked for some browsers and not others.

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

i {
  border: solid #ffb200;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.down {
  color: #ffb200;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.right {
  color: #ffb200;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.mainnav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function myFunction( e ) {
  
    var x = e.target.nextElementSibling,
        y = e.target.firstChild;
        
    if ( x.style.display === 'none' || x.style.display === '' ) {
    
      x.style.display = 'block';
      
      y.classList.add( 'down' );
      y.classList.remove( 'right' );
      
    } else {
    
      x.style.display = 'none';
      
      y.classList.remove( 'down' );
      y.classList.add( 'right');
      
    }
    
  }
</script>

<h3 class="sidebar-heading">
  <a class="sidebar-heading" href="#logins"> <u>SYSTEM LOGINS</u></a>
</h3>
<h4 onclick="myFunction( event );" class="sidebar-heading2"><i class="right" style="top:-50px"></i> Login types</h4>
<div class="mainnav">
  <nav id="mainnav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Admin">login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Student">Student login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Guest">Guest login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

As a side note I wouldn't inline your event handlers, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved my problem. 

Please may you give me more of an explanation for what you did so I can understand the change better

Comment: Anything you pass into a function should be listed as an argument (parameter) that the function expects in the function definition. If I had a function to square a number its function definition would be `function square( number ) { return number * number; }` and I would use it like so `var x = square( 4 ); // x = 16`. If I didn't define `number` in the function definition, i.e. `function square() { return number * number; }`, and use it like before, `16` doesn't get mapped to the `number` argument (variable) for use in the function.

Comment: There's other considerations too but the lack of referenced to the data that was passed into the function is the point takeaway here. Also note that the parameter name in your example **does not** have to be the same. In fact, I'm going to make that change now so you can see clearly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you for all the clarification and information. This will improve my code definitely. 

While i am at it why does the following code change the color of the heading to black when I hover over the heading? I want it to stay orange

<h3 class ="sidebar-heading"><a class ="sidebar-heading" href="#logins"> <u>SYSTEM LOGINS</u></a></h3> 

.sidebar-heading{
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #ffb200;
 display: block;
 padding: 1px 9px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;;
}

Comment: @LyubomirValchev that's outside of the scope of this question. I suggest asking another question. That being said, I quick added the CSS to the demo above and it does not change to black for me, it stays orange. You must have some other CSS causing your issue.